# RegionPlot3D is giving wrong plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, regions

I am seeing discrepancies between plots obtained for same region using `Region` and `RegionPlot3D`,

When I use

```
reg4 = ImplicitRegion[
   A1 > 0 && 
    A2 > 0 && (\[Mu] < -((3 Abs[A1])/2)) && (\[Mu] < -(3/2) Sqrt[3]
        Abs[A2]) && (2 \[Mu] + Sqrt[
       A1^2 + 16 A2^2 + 8 Abs[A1] Abs[A2]] < 0), {{A1, 0, 2}, {A2, 0, 
     2}, {\[Mu], -1.5, 0}}];
Region[reg4, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"A1", "A2", "\[Mu]"}]
```

[image]

If I use `RegionPlot3D` then I get

```
RegionPlot3D[
 A1 > 0 && 
  A2 > 0 && (\[Mu] < -((3 Abs[A1])/2)) && (\[Mu] < -(3/2) Sqrt[3]
      Abs[A2]) && (2 \[Mu] + Sqrt[
     A1^2 + 16 A2^2 + 8 Abs[A1] Abs[A2]] < 0), {A1, 0, 2}, {A2, 0, 
  2}, {\[Mu], -1.5, 0}, Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {"A1", "A2", "\[Mu]"}]
```

[image]

As if the surface is smoothened in this figure, so the plot is also wrong.

**Why two different graphics for the same region?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

The [`Abs`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Abs.html) appear to be causing most of the roughness of the [`Region`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Region.html) plot. Perhaps because `Abs` does not have a derivative. Since you are dealing with real numbers, `Abs[x] == Sqrt[x^2]`.

```
reg4 = ImplicitRegion[
    A1 > 0 && 
     A2 > 0 && (μ < -((3 Abs[A1])/2)) &&
     (μ < -(3/2) Sqrt[3] Abs[
         A2]) &&
     (2 μ + Sqrt[A1^2 + 16 A2^2 + 8 Abs[A1] Abs[A2]] < 0),
    {{A1, 0, 2}, {A2, 0, 2}, {μ, -1.5, 0}}] /.
   Abs[x_] :> Sqrt[x^2];
```

**EDIT:** Alternatively, use `FullSimplify` within definition of `reg4`

```
reg4 = ImplicitRegion[
   A1 > 0 && 
     A2 > 0 &&
     (μ < -((3 Abs[A1])/2)) &&
     (μ < -(3/2) Sqrt[
         3] Abs[A2]) &&
     (2 μ + 
        Sqrt[A1^2 + 16 A2^2 + 8 Abs[A1] Abs[A2]] < 0) //
    FullSimplify,
   {{A1, 0, 2}, {A2, 0, 2}, {μ, -3/2, 0}}];

reg = Region[reg4,
  Axes -> True,
  AxesLabel -> {"A1", "A2", "μ"},
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

[image]

To get a more accurate [`RegionPlot3`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot3.html) increase the [`PlotPoints`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html) and [`MaxRecursion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxRecursion.html)

```
RegionPlot3D[
 A1 > 0 && A2 > 
   0 && (μ < -((3 Abs[A1])/2)) && (μ < -(3/2) Sqrt[3] Abs[
      A2]) && (2 μ + Sqrt[A1^2 + 16 A2^2 + 8 Abs[A1] Abs[A2]] < 0), {A1, 
  0, 2}, {A2, 0, 2}, {μ, -1.5, 0}, Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {"A1", "A2", "μ"}, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]